# The date format in the CSV file reverts back to dd/mm/yyyy from set dd/mm/yy

Tags: vba

I'm using the following code (which is being executed on a .CSV file):

```
....code

ws1.Range("E2:E300000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"

....code
```

The problem is that even though the date format is defined (by the code above) as "dd/mm/yy", after saving and reopening the file date format reverts back to "dd/mm/yyyy". It seems it only happens with .CSV files (I've tried with xlsm and the format remained as "dd/mm/yy").

Any ideas how to preserve defined "dd/mm/yy" format?

Comment: CSV file do not retain formatting so excel will format it to the standard each time it is opened.  And each time you will need to reformat the column back.  Or you can change your local settings to `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Thanks for that Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Scott_Craner mentioned CSV does not retain the format. It seems that the only sensible way to end this question is for me to post this statement. Thanks